# Visualize Syslog on OSX

Tags: logs

I'm looking for a GUI (or terminal if there is no GUI) application that provides the following:

- Visualization of syslog logs.
- Filtering: For example, I can filter a particular type of logs, a particular PID, etc..

Basically, I have an application that logs to syslog. I want to read these logs comfortably. Console.app only does show the syslog file, which is, not quite different than opening the file in a note pad.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying the console does not show your desired logs? Or, that you are not able to enter a filter to just show your desired logs?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Console.App "just" show the logs. Like opening it with a text editor would. There is no features like coloring, filtering, etc... It is actually even worse since you are can't change the font size Console.app

Comment: The are all kinds of filters. What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: The latest: 10.14.3

Answer (score 2):

The **new** console.app will let you set filters and lets you set options to display certain info. Console.app comes with your mac and is in the Utilities folder which is in the Applications folder. Or more clearly its path is /Applications/Utilities

The console.app is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a screenshot so that I'm sure that I have a different version than you?

Comment: sure. give me a minute.

Comment: These features are only available for Apple OSX logs (ASL) but not for syslog (System.log file).

Answer (score 2):

You have filters such as the following:

[image]

Here are the shortcuts to enter:

[image]